# Prove $\tanh(x) = ax + b$ has at most three solutions

Tags: calculus

Let $b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$, I'd like to prove that $$\tanh(x) = ax + b$$ has at least one, but at **most three solutions**.
That the equation has always at least one solution follows by the intermediate value theorem (i.e., both sides are real continuous functions and $\tanh(x)$ is bounded, while $ax + b$ is not).

Yet, I lack a concrete approach to prove that the equation has at most three solutions (even though this is easily apparent from a graphical observation).

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: @runway44 This question uses the hyperbolic tangent, not the regular one.

Comment: You said you did "graphical observations". Well, what did your learn about different values for $a, b$? If you found something useful, you can definitely work backwards to obtain a concrete proof.

Comment: If we could prove that the second derivate of tanh(x) has only one root, namely $0$, we could use Rolle's theorem.

Comment: Other info; see that $\max(\tanh{x})' = 1$ at $x = 0$ and $\lim_{x \to \pm \infty}{(\tanh{x})'} \to 0$. What does this indicate about particular values of $a$?

Comment: Hi. There is a similar question here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4029249/proving-that-there-are-3-solutions-at-most-fx-ex-ax2bxc/4617104#4617104

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g(x)=\tanh (x)-ax-b$ , Since $(g(+\infty),g(-\infty))=(+\infty,-\infty)$ or $(-\infty,+\infty)$, by intermediate value theorem, $g(x)=0$ has at least one solution. $g'(x)=\operatorname{sech}^2(x)-a$, so $g'(x)=0$ has at most two solutions, by Rolle's  theorem, $g(x)=0$ has at most three solutions.

Comment: Great, thanks, simple and intuitive solution, I like it.